# Git hook for updating Git submodule on branch change

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules, githooks

I'm working with some old code that makes use of Git submodules. The code has several divergent branches which are actively being used, and each of these branches depends on unfortunately a different revision of the relevant submodules; [this has made development extremely complicated](http://slopjong.de/2013/06/04/git-why-submodules-are-evil/). One of the problems I face is that, when I switch between branches from e.g. `master` to `newfeature-foo` using `git checkout newfeature-foo`, the state of the submodules remains at that of `master`, which often causes compile errors and even worse can cause differences in runtime behavior that wreaks havoc with user testing and general sanity.

For example, given the `.gitmodules` configuration:

```
[submodule "robotcontroller"]
    path = robotcontroller
    url = https://coolrobots.com/repos/robotcontroller
    branch = master
    ignore = dirty
```

- the branch `master` at commit *77d4697* has a reference to `robotcontroller @ f57d1b3`
- the branch `newfeature-foo` at *b38d29f* has a reference to `robotcontroller @ 60b27d4`
- the branch `master` at *873639f* doesn't have the submodule `robotcontroller` at all
- the branch `newfeature-foo` at *301dca4* has a reference to `robotcontroller @ bdf5991`

Is there no way e.g. using Git hooks to force the automatic complete re-checking-out of all submodules listed in a `.gitmodules` file when it changes on checkout of the "root" Git repository?

Comment: You can use `git submodule update` in your post-checkout hook if the checkout changed branches. The fact that the submodule *goes away* in some commits makes this trickier, though.

Comment: `git checkout --recurse-submodules newfeature-foo`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mort if you don't know the repository has submodules or if you're just dealing with tons of different repositories throughout the day, that extra `--recurse-submodules` is **extremely** annoying.

Comment: Ok, but then you could perhaps put that in your question. "There is an existing simple solution to this problem, but I find it annoying for the following reasons... and I would like a different solution with the following simpler properties..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post-checkout` hook that removes `robotcontroller` and update all submodules.

```
#!/bin/sh

# post-checkout hook that update submodules

prev_HEAD="$1"
new_HEAD="$2"
new_branch="$3"

if [ "$new_branch" = 1 ]; then
   if ! grep -Fq robotcontroller .gitmodules; then
      rm -rf robotcontroller
   fi

   git submodule update
fi

exit 0
```

PS. The correct term for the root Git repository is "superproject". :-)

Comment: Thanks; that was easier than I'd feared. Might you know of an elegant way off the top of your head for generalizing this to any and all potential entries in `.gitmodules`? I can't always know what submodule name(s) are present, and writing bespoke logic inside the `sh` script for parsing `.gitmodules` would be cumbersome.

Comment: As @torek has said it would be trickier. Either compare `.gitmodules` from `prev_HEAD` and `new_HEAD` (and parse the diff) or have a list of all possible submodules and grep the one by one in `.gitmodules`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are a lot of things going on in your repo that make things confusing. We could go through a lot of back-and-forth to find the settings that are conflicting, but here's what I would do:

### Get rid of `ignore = dirty`

This just hides useful information - perhaps the submodule is not checking out cleanly because it would override files. At the very least, confirm that the submodule is clean before trying any operations on it - `cd mysubmodule` and `git status` = clean

Comment: Are you sure you're answering this question?