# Git submodule revert commit

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule `sub` in a Git project `super`. Now there are multiple branches of `super` and each may point to another commit of `sub`. Changing the branch of `super` via

```
>$ git checkout <branchname>
```

does not properly adapt `sub` to point to the correct commit again, though. Instead the result of

```
>$ git status
```

contains a *modified* entry for `sub`.

This is only one of several situations where one might want to revert any modifications of `sub` and checkout the commit to which `super` actually points.

For files you can always run

```
>$ git checkout -- path/to/file
```

to revert any modifications. So I am basically looking for an equivalent call to revert submodules in a similarly quick and simple manner.

I know this is possible by combination of two commands:

```
>$ git submodule deinit -f /path/to/sub
>$ git submodule update --init --recursive /path/to/sub
```

but I am looking for a shorter version which might be easier to remember and faster to type ;)

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git hook for updating Git submodule on branch change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176805/git-hook-for-updating-git-submodule-on-branch-change)

Comment: You do not need to deinit and re-init, just `git submodule update`. Or, use Thiru's answer if your Git is new enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by torek, skipping the deinit step works well. Thus the following command does the job for me:

```
git submodule update --recursive /path/to/submodule
```

Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: For me, this changes nothing. Git reports no changes to commit or push, so this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this command and check?

> `git checkout --recurse-submodules {branch_name}`

Comment: That's probably the best method but requires Git version 2.13 or later (and 2.13.2 has a bug fix for submodules that contain their own submodules).

Comment: I cannot test it as my version of Git is too old. However, I think this is not what I was looking for.I do not want to checkout a specific branch, but the commit the `super` points to, thereby dropping any local changes in `sub`.