# Revert changes to a submodule in a commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, revert

**Question**

Given an already pushed commit `sha1` that contains a change to a submodule, and some other changes to other files, how do I revert only the change to the submodule, but keep the changes to the other files? (I.e., it is not an option to revert the whole commit.)

**Attempt so far**

I tried this, based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7196615/3398271) in the related question:

`git show some_commit_sha1 -- path/to/submodule | git apply -R`

but obviously it does not work.

I would be surprised if it did, as the diff is just this:

```
git show some_commit_sha1 -- path/to/submodule
[...]
-Subproject commit abcdef12345....
+Subproject commit 98765432109....
```

(I guess `git apply -R` can't do much with that.)

**Related but not duplicated questions:**

[Revert changes to a file in a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620775/revert-changes-to-a-file-in-a-commit)  This is exactly what I want to do, however not with a file, but a submodule.

[How do I revert my changes to a git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906554/how-do-i-revert-my-changes-to-a-git-submodule) This is for reverting "local" (not yet committed) changes

[Git submodule revert commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173319/git-submodule-revert-commit) Title seems to be exactly what I need, but then the question asks about something else (if I understand correctly it's about changing the content of the submodule on various branches)

Answer (score 0):

**Submodule Commit Revert**

> First go to command Prompt Then go to submodule that you want to
>   revert.

**1) cd ../submodule name**

> commit id will be available in GIT commits in difference in PR.

**2) git checkout commit id**

> Check git Status

**3) git status**

> See output on command prompt submodule look like in Red colour , just check.

**4) modified: ../submodule name**

> Then add changes to GIT for push.

**5) git add ../.**

> Check status again

**6) git status**

> See output on command prompt submodule look like in green colour, just check.

**7) modified: ../submodule name**

> Then Push changes to GIT

**8) git push**

Note : if push not done form command prompt then you can push through `Android Studio` in case of android OR `Source Tree` OR some other GIT editor.

`Android Studio` is better option in case of android if you can only revert specific part of files of wrong submodule commit , for tease you can only select those files that should only get merged wrongly.