# Why aren't git submodule operations automatic?

Tags: git, git-submodules

It seems like by design git's submodule operations are manual. As a moderately-adept git user, I want to understand this design decision. In particular, it seems like the least surprising thing for `git pull` or `git checkout` to do is to check pull/check out the appropriate branch/comment, then update all submodules to match their corresponding commits. Why?

It appears that the above functionality is enabled if I set

```
[submodule]
        recurse = true
```

in my `~/.gitconfig`. But even then, when a colleague adds a new module, when I `git pull master`, I don't get the new module even though it shows up in `.gitmodules`. If I check `.gitmodules` for new ones and then do `git submodule update --init MODULEPATH`, I get it. But again, why would this manual interaction be the desired behavior? When I `pull`/`checkout`, wouldn't I (almost?) always want all the modules update to match?

Bonus: Is there a way to automatically have `git` fetch and check out new submodules? I.e., is there a Just Works mode for submodules. And if not, what do I not understand about the design of submodules that makes the default behavior desirable?

Comment: *I want to understand design decisions* and *why would this manual interaction be the desired behavior?* are hardly suitable questions for StackOverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: *Is there a way to automatically have git fetch and check out new submodules?* [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50178825/7976758). See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+switch+branches+hook

Comment: I understand why it's not a great question. I posed it this way because after much searching, I felt like I was finding some partial answers to my practical question, but no overarching explanation why I was just not groking the default behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899826/7976758